# Solving an integral equation (and ODE)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In solving the below integral equation (which turns into being a separable ODE), why is the solution $$y=\sqrt{2\ln{(x)}+4}$$ and not $$y=\pm\sqrt{2\ln{(x)}+4}.$$

Equation in question:
$$y\left(x\right)=2+\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{ty\left(t\right)}dt,\ \ x>0$$

I suspect it has something to with $x$ being greater than zero.  Could you please explain this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually has to do with the initial condition; the general solution of the resulting separable equation $y'(x) = \frac{1}{xy(x)}$ is $y(x) = \pm\sqrt{2\ln x + C}$, but from the integral equation you know that $y(1) = 2$. Since $y$ can only be positive everywhere or negative, this fixes the positive sign in the general solution and allows us to calculate $C = 4$.